# CakePHP Pagination Helper Sort Nulls Last

Tags: sorting, cakephp, null, pagination, helper

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6 and I am trying to use the Pagination helper to sort data, but I want to add Nulls Last to my query.

Has anyone achieved this functionality?

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('status_id', null, array('direction' => 'desc'));
```

This doesn't work for because the Pagination helper is not setup to handle it.

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('status_id', null, array('direction' => 'desc NULLS LAST'));
```

Comment: I am fairly certain that this specific functionality should be added in the controller (namingly around the PaginatorComponent) or even model layer, not in the view! Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I am using Cake 2.3.6.   To me it makes sense that nulls come last anytime one sorts either ascending or descending.  Can you think of a case when you'd want nulls first?  Perhaps it can be built into the core or the paginator component.

Comment: I don't disagree. Maybe you can add it as a feature request to support this. But as said, it should not be something you can enable from the view layer.

Comment: Thanks again.  To get me started, where in the Model or Controller would I add code that will play nicely with the paginator helper?

Comment: It would probably be something on the paginator component. Although I dont know if the Database classes would even support this feature currently. You can also open a simple ticket - stating only what you want. And no code yet.

Comment: Great.  I will create a feature ticket at https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.

Comment: I hacked together a query substitution in my model's beforeFind function and it works.  But I tried putting the same code my AppModel.php but for some reason the query never hits the AppModel.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't the most efficient and I am sure I could be assigning by reference, but this works for my model.

```
function beforeFind( $query)
{
    $queryOrderArray = $query['order'];
    if(isset($queryOrderArray)){
        $i = 0;
        foreach($queryOrderArray as $myOrderArray){
            if(isset($myOrderArray) && is_array($myOrderArray)){
                foreach($myOrderArray as $myField => $myOrder){
                    if($myOrder == 'desc'){
                        $myOrder .= ' NULLS LAST';
                        $myOrderArray[$myField] = $myOrder;
                    }
                }
            }
            $queryOrderArray[$i] = $myOrderArray;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $query['order'] = $queryOrderArray;
    return $query;
}
```